# Proof by induction when upper bound isn't $n$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, proof-explanation

I'm new to doing proofs by induction and am having trouble. I am wondering if a sum having an upper bound not equal to $n$ changes the problem. The initial is

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{i}{2^i} = 2 - \frac{n+1}{2^{n-1}}$$

I can do the base case where $n = 1$. However, because of the bound, I'm not sure what to do next. I'm not sure what to do with the bounds because when I did

$$2 - \frac{k+1}{2^{k-1}}+\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}$$

which is $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{i}{2^i}$ + $P(k+1)$
I ended up with $$2 - \frac{{(k+1)}{(2^{k+1}+2^{k-1}})}{2^{2k}}$$ which I cannot figure out how to use to solve the proof, and I'm not confident that it's correct.

Since the bound ends at $k-1$, not $k$, should I set up the second part as
$$2 - \frac{k+1}{2^{k-1}}+\frac{k}{2^{k}}?$$

Comment: You have taken a wrong turn in the second & third equations. But the fourth equation is correct ... Common denominator of the last two terms $2^k$, neaten the numerator & you are there.

Comment: You can just define $m=n-1$ and substitute in $m$ to make the upper bound simpler.  You don't have to.  You can still assume it works up to $k$ and prove it works up to $k+1$ from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i\le n}\frac{i}{2^i}&=\sum_{i\le n-1}\frac{i}{2^i}+\frac{n}{2^n} \\
&=\left(2-\frac{n+1}{2^{n-1}}\right)+\frac{n}{2^n} \\
&=2-\frac{2n+2}{2^{n}}+\frac{n}{2^n} \\
&=2-\frac{n+2}{2^{n}}.
\end{align}

Comment: Why am I able to end the proof here? I cannot get this back into the form of the original sum.

Comment: Are you sure? This is exactly in the original form, where you substitute each $n$ with $n+1$ (in all places where you see it)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\frac {i}{2^i})$ and $g(n)=2-\frac {n+1}{2^{n-1}}.$ $$\text {We have }\quad f(n+1)-f(n)=\frac {n}{2^n}......(A).$$ $$\text { We have }\quad g(n+1)-g(n)=\left(2-\frac {n+2}{2^n}\right)-\left(2-\frac {n+1}{2^{n-1}}\right)=$$ $$=\left(-\frac {n+2}{2^n}\right)+\left(\frac {n+1}{2^{n-1}}\right)=$$ $$=\left(-\frac {n+2}{2^n}\right)+\left(\frac {2n+2}{2^n}\right)=$$ $$=\frac {n}{2^n}......(B).$$  From $(A)$ and $(B)$ we have $f(n+1)-f(n)=g(n+1)-g(n)$  for every $n.$  So if $f(n)=g(n)$ then $$f(n+1)=(f(n+1)-f(n))+f(n)=$$ $$=(g(n+1)-g(n))+f(n)=$$ $$=(g(n+1)-g(n))+g(n)=g(n+1).$$ So, by induction, $f(1)=g(1)$ implies that $f(n)=g(n)$ for every $n,$ and we do indeed have $f(1)=g(1)=0.$

This method is applicable to a wide variety of problems.